# Laravel reset password add where condition

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I have two separated Auths for the project one for Doctors (Login, Register & Reset)[Accounts Table] and the other for Patients (clients) (Login, Register & Reset) [Patients table].

Each Patient can be registered with the same mail with any doctor (Account).

i have done all the stuff but my problem is when the patient resets his password  inside specific doctor account. Laravel changes the password of the  patient mail in patients table ..

My question is: how to add condition to resetPassword method

**Ex: where mail = $mail and account_id = $account_id**

i successed to override the sendRequestResetLinkMail method by

PatientAuth\ForgotPasswordController.php:

```
    public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email',
    ]);

    $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink([
        'email'      => $request->input('email'),
        'account_id' => Hashids::decode($request->segment(3)),
    ]);

    return $response == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
        ? $this->sendResetLinkResponse($response)
        : $this->sendResetLinkFailedResponse($request, $response);
}
```

ResetPasswordController.php:

```
class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
```

{

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('lang');
}

//Client redirect path
protected function redirectTo(Request $request)
{
    return route('WSG.view.home', $request->segments(3));
}
//trait for handling reset Password for patient / client
use ResetsPasswords;
//Show form to patient / client where they can reset password
public function showResetForm(Request $request, $id, $token = null)
{

    $id                  = Hashids::decode($id);

    $main_settings       = WSGeneratorMainSetting::where('account_id', $id)->first();


    return view('doctor_website.layouts.reset',
        [
            'token'         => $token,
            'email'         => $request->email,
            'main_settings' => $main_settings,
        ]
    );
}

protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    return $request->only(
        'email', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'account_id' , 'token'
    );
}

//returns Password broker of seller
public function broker()
{
    return Password::broker('clients');
}
//returns authentication guard of seller
protected function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard('client');
}
```

}

Comment: You can also pass one field as user_role and check for the same

Comment: @Gurpalsingh can you explain more, please ? .. thank you in advance

Comment: You are having two module one for doctor and other for patient. you need to create a user_role table. it should contain id,user_id,role.
whenever user registered you have to make one entry on this table. if  doctor add 1 for patient add 2.
Again check this at the time of login